# why am I getting password mismatch by bcrypt compare even though both password and hashed password from database matches?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, hash, bcrypt

For user authentication, I'm storing passwords by hashing using bcrypt which is stored in MongoDB cluster but when I try to authenticate the user using the same string I get the wrong comparison with bcrypt.compare says mismatch. Here is the code I'm trying to run both for saving and authenticating

```
import bcrypt
salt = bcrypt.gensalt()    
password = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), salt)
```

here  is nodejs code for authenticating based on user entry

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
    var user = this;
    console.log((passw === user.password) ? 'passwords match' : 'passwords dont match' );
    console.log(passw +" "+ user.password )
    bcrypt.compare(passw, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        console.log(passw +" "+ user.password +" " +isMatch )
        if(err) {
            return cb(err)
        }
        cb(null, isMatch)
    })
}
```

here is the print of generated hashed password for string '123'

```
hashed password b'$2b$12$URN6pyD4SsOgIXALvr.jIuy2hvxlxva.ioamDNtMhAwvWb9/nLdhO'
```

in mongo db it stores it as binary
[image: entered database]
password:Binary('JDJiJDEyJFVSTjZweUQ0U3NPZ0lYQUx2ci5qSXV5Mmh2eGx4dmEuaW9hbUROdE1oQXd2V2I5L25MZGhP', 0)

when I try to authenticate with the user-entered password I get a mismatch even though I entered the same string while hashing

```
123 $2b$12$URN6pyD4SsOgIXALvr.jIuy2hvxlxva.ioamDNtMhAwvWb9/nLdhO null
```

it throws null even though both are the same
for the user which got saved in a database

```
user found{ _id: 60479960c20181a14badf6e0,
  Name: 'boolbool',
  phoneno: '2828',
  uploadid: 'dilshan',
  password: '$2b$12$URN6pyD4SsOgIXALvr.jIuy2hvxlxva.ioamDNtMhAwvWb9/nLdhO' }
```

I tried encoding & checking password

```
bcrypt.compare(utf8.encode(passw), utf8.encode(user.password), function (err, isMatch)
```

but still, it says null
what am I doing wrong? can someone point out my mistake? that will be very helpful

Comment: here you use bcrypt did you install the compiler and build the dependencies: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcr...n-Instructions. In many cases using bcryptjs is easier 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Comment: bcryptjs is what I'm using